# Selenium with headless chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium, headless

I have testing environment which is perfectly working with chrome driver in desktop mode. I am using some javascript injections (everything works) f.e.:

```
public static void ForceFillInput(this Driver driver, string selector, string value)
        {
            var javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver.webDriver;
            javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript($"$(\"{selector}\").val(\"{value}\")");
        }
```

but when i want to run it in headless mode

```
AddArguments("--headless")
```

it will just fail on

```
"$ is not defined"
```

Can somebody help me how to inject js/jquery into headless solution?

M.

Comment: Can you explain the heading `$` in `$"$(\"{selector}\").val(\"{value}\")"` if it's not a type error,  I see you mark your question with `Javascript`, but your code looks like `Java`

Comment: @yong, more like C#. The `$` in front is to declare an Interpolated String. I guess the JavaScript tag is for the JavaScript code executed by `ExecuteScript`.

Comment: @FlorentB. Yes, that is exactly what is it. Its called from c#, but i am executing js

Comment: @MartinFric, did you find the reason for this? the same error is happening to me, only when using browser in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

your Javascript snippet used `jQuery` api. In modern web development, we put Javascript at the end of HTML page to let browser to load javascript at last, so that static resources (like picture/image/text content) can display earlier as possible, withing this way to improve user experience when user open website.

I think your page also put `jQuery` at the end to load, try add some wait/sleep before `ExecuteScript` to wait browser complete load `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the shorthand for JQuery is not yet created at the time your script is executed.

Use a waiter to wait for JQuery and for the selector to be found:

```
public static void ForceFillInput(this Driver driver, string selector, string value)
{
    string JS_SET_VALUE = 
      "var e; return !!window.$ && (e = window.$(arguments[0])).length > 0 && (e.val(arguments[1]), true);";

    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
      .until(ctx => (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)ctx).ExecuteScript(JS_SET_VALUE, selector, value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, in normal mode it can pass, but in headless mode it is just looping as it cant find selector. I reworked it like this `string JS_SET_VALUE = "var e; return !!window.$ && (e = window.$(arguments[0])).length > 0;";

            new WebDriverWait(driver.webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(ctx => (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)ctx).ExecuteScript(JS_SET_VALUE, selector));`

Comment: I can see that document.readyState is 'complete' but when i try jQuery.active, it says that jQuery is not defined